# Applying subgrouping to a subgroup in R

Tags: r, subset

I have this code to create two subset columns based on quantiles, one column for median split and one column for quartile split.

```
 mtcars <- subset(mtcars, select = c("cyl", "disp"))
 mtcars$median_split <- ifelse(mtcars$disp <= median(mtcars$disp), "below_median","above_median")
 mtcars$quantile_split <- cut(mtcars$disp, breaks = c(0, quantile(mtcars$disp)),labels = c("1_quartile",paste0(1:4, "_quartile")))
```

This works nicely for the whole dataset, but how can I do this for each `cyl` separately, please?

So, I am hoping to print the median/quartile split labels based on `disp` values within each `cyl` group. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  select(cyl, disp) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(median_split = ifelse(disp <=median(disp), "below_median","above_median"),
         quartile_split = cut(disp, breaks = c(0, quantile(disp)), labels = c("1_quartile",paste0(1:4, "_quartile")))) %>%
  arrange(cyl)
```

This code groups the data by the `cyl` column and then computes the `median_split` and `quartile_split` based on the `disp` values within each `cyl` group.

Comment: Woohoooo! Awesome! Thank you so much.